# Return random order with every shipment that is applicable to the order

Tags: random, ssms

Hi I am super new to SSMS.

I need to create a random audit that will look at one order and all the activities that is attached to that order to return. It will return top 40 order # randomly but with multiple activities.

```
Example table
Order#       Activities
1            Jump
1            Jump
1            Run
3            Jump 
3            Run
3            Duck
4            Kick
5            Run
6            Duck
6            Kick
```

So far this is what I have.

```
Select *
From Project
Order by NEWID()
```

I found something similar but I did not understand it.

Comment: What would be an acceptable (random) output for that sample input table?

Comment: the Query i have will produce random order# now i need to figure out how to return all activities that are tied to the order#

Comment: I think i might have to do an inner join with the random query to the table itself to return. Randomized order# with all activities available. What do you think?

Comment: I think you are correct. Give a try and update your question with your personal attempt if it does not work like you expect it.